# Generic Abstract Class

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code which is fine...

```
namespace GenericAbstract
{
    public interface INotifModel
    {
        string Data { get; set; }
    }

    public interface INotif<T> where T: INotifModel
    {
       T Model { get; set; }
    }

    public interface INotifProcessor<in T> where T : INotif<INotifModel>
    {
        void Yell(T notif);
    }

    public class HelloWorldModel : INotifModel
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }

        public HelloWorldModel()
        {
            Data = "Hello world!";
        }
    }

    public class HelloWorldNotif : INotif<HelloWorldModel>
    {
        public HelloWorldModel Model { get; set; }

        public HelloWorldNotif()
        {
            Model = new HelloWorldModel();
        }
    }

    public class HelloWorldProcessor<T> : INotifProcessor<T> where T : INotif<INotifModel>
    {
        public void Yell(T notif)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there are 3 interfaces and each of those is implemented.

However, I would like the processor to be implemented like this:

```
public class HelloWorldProcessor : INotifProcessor<HelloWorldNotif<HelloWorldModel>>
{
    public void Yell(HelloWorldNotif<HelloWorldModel> notif)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But i get the following error:

> The non-generic type 'HelloWorldNotif' cannot be used with type arguments

I want the HelloWorldProcessor to implement `INotifProcessor` only for `HelloWorldNotif`...

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong..

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking. `HelloWorldNotif` already implements `INotif<HelloWorldModel>` (and isn't generic) so why would you then want it to take another generic type of `HelloWorldModel`?

Comment: Error message is clear.  `HelloWorldNotif` is not a generic, so you can't use `HelloWorldNotif<...>`.

Comment: @DavidG I want the HelloWorldProcessor to implement INotifProcessor only for HelloWorldNotif...

Comment: Yes, you already said that, but like I (and Amy) said, `HelloWorldNotif` isn't generic.

Comment: @DavidG, I know it's not a generic type. But how can I create a Processor that implements INotifProcessor and "yells" HelloworldNotif"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you first have to make `INotif<T>` co-variant.  That means that the `Model` property has to be read only for the interface (it can still have a public `set` in an implementation).  Then to fix your immediate error you don't put the `<HelloWorldModel>` after `HelloWorldNotif` because it's already a `INotif<HelloWorldModel>`

```
public interface INotifModel
{
    string Data { get; set; }
}

public interface INotif<out T> where T : INotifModel
{
    T Model { get; }
}

public interface INotifProcessor<in T> where T : INotif<INotifModel>
{
    void Yell(T notif);
}

public class HelloWorldModel : INotifModel
{
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public HelloWorldModel()
    {
        Data = "Hello world!";
    }
}

public class HelloWorldNotif : INotif<HelloWorldModel>
{
    public HelloWorldModel Model { get; set; }

    public HelloWorldNotif()
    {
        Model = new HelloWorldModel();
    }
}

public class HelloWorldProcessor<T> : INotifProcessor<T> where T : INotif<INotifModel>
{
    public void Yell(T notif)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class HelloWorldProcessor : INotifProcessor<HelloWorldNotif>
{
    public void Yell(HelloWorldNotif notif)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then I guess your implementation would be something like

```
Console.WriteLine(notif.Model.Data);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said and/or implied out you've already got HelloWorldNotif fully specified. So to translate this:

> I want the HelloWorldProcessor to implement INotifProcessor only for
>   HelloWorldNotif

To C#, I think you mean:

```
public class HelloWorldProcessor : INotifProcessor<HelloWorldNotif>
{
    public void Yell(HelloWorldNotif notif)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: While that is likely what the OP was going for and it handles the immediate error this also will not compile because `HelloWOrldNotif` is not a `INotif<INotifModel>`, it's a `INotif<HelloWorldModel>` and `INotif<T>` would both to be co-variant for that to work.